# Javascript fetch request doesn't load php data on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, php, heroku

I'm working on a project which is hosted on Heroku and I'm making a call to a PHP file on backend using the Javascript fetch API. Here is the code,

```
fetch('./api/file.php').then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

And for some reason I'm not loading anything from the backend the file loads fine, the developer tools on the browser shows that file is called by making the request, however there is no data being loaded.

[image]

However when I opened the file.php from the browser by typing the URL the data is shown on the same file.php file on the browser.

So how come that there is no response from the fetch request but have the data when accessing the file by typing the URL on browser? Does this have to do something with heroku? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: could you show the tab with the request/headers

Comment: @Meiko Hope this helps :) http://pastebin.com/Pf99jb2k http://pastebin.com/YAfKvTNj http://pastebin.com/6iVdPApG